# Comma separated String looping and checking

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

I am not sure what is the best way to achieve the same. I have comma separated string like

> "sdf,sd,gth,ht,hjh,fds,nhgs"

I have to iterate through the whole string and match it with a value. If the value does not matches then truncate the last part of the string after comma and check for the rest whole string.

For example if the value does not matches with

> "sdf,sd,gth,ht,hjh,fds,nhgs"

then truncate the last value after comma and compare the value with

> "sdf,sd,gth,ht,hjh,fds"

this time.

Keep iterating through the whole string till it does not matches the value.

Any help in this regard at the earliest is much appreciated.

Comment: Any specific programming language?

Comment: I am trying to achieve it in c#

Comment: What language and what have you tried?

Comment: You may probably try with String.Split method and then do let us know what efforts you have put in!!

Comment: I have already tried with .Split(',') method not sure how to iterate throught it everytime. Any working code sample for the said problem will be helpfull

Comment: @user2615501:- Could you share what you have tried?

Comment: This does not make sense. As described you could compare your value to a truncated version of your string and just make sure that the next character is a comma or end of string... I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var stringToMatch = "abc,def";
        var testString = "abc,def,ghi,jkl";

        bool matches = testString.StartsWith( stringToMatch );
```